нужна ли запятая "с помощью"
И(,)с помощью простых слов(,) можно коротко и ясно изложить мысли

Предлагается правка в качестве варианта:
И даже с помощью простых слов / можно коротко и ясно изложить мысли.
Пояснение
Правка стилистическая. В этом случае предложение читается более корректно и не возникают сомнения относительно знаков.
Предложение простое, смыслового выделения обстоятельственного оборота нет. Интонационно предложение делится на две части с помощью произносительной паузы, но запятая не ставится.
Союз И — присоединительный, даже — усилительная частица.
В исходном варианте также нет обособления оборота.
